# AngularJS $promise not working in ngresource

Tags: angularjs

For me, `$promise.then()` is not working. It's throwing the following error:

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Example code:

```
$scope.query = UserService.query();
$scope.query.$promise.then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/manoj_antony32/ybsvk0vo/)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: what version of angularjs you are using

Answer (score 1):

Using angularjs 1.6, It is working fine:

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldjod1gn/1)

```
$scope.query = UserService.query();
$scope.query.$promise.then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```